# facebook app loading slow in android

Tags: java, android

i took the example from

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/ now whenever

i run the app...either it takes too long time to load the face book sign-up or it never loads...it stays in whit screen with heading
[image: this is the way it loads the fc app]

now what shall i do to load in a faster way...

`public class MyGreatActivity extends Activity {

```
Facebook facebook = new Facebook("20875929582353");

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    facebook.authorize(this, new DialogListener() {

        @Override
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(DialogError e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }


    });
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

}`

Answer (score 1):

I just tried your example code and it works for me. It first shows a loading dialog and then the page shows an error message. Maybe not what you want, but no freezes.

Are you sure you have an internet connection at the moment in your emulator? I know from experience that sometimes the emulator just looses the internet connection and you have to restart it.